# работа setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Здравствуйте. Не получается самостоятельно разобраться с setTimeout. В чём проблема - необходимо переключать стили элемента по событию через паузу. Что я делаю внутри обработчика события - `window.setTimeout(document.querySelector(".some-selector").classList.toggle('active'), 300);`
Всё работает, но без задержки. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все очень просто. Первым аргументом для `setTimeout` нужно передавать функцию, вторым - время задержки. Вы же передаете первым аргументом результат выполнения функций `document.querySelector(".some-selector").classList.toggle('active')`

Т.е. по сути передаете первым аргументом то, что вернет вам вызов `.toggle('active')`. А вернет он вам `true` или `false`, если верить [справочке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

Чтобы сделать правильно, вам нужно обернуть код, который необходимо выполнить, в анонимную функцию. Вот так:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector(".some-selector").classList.toggle('active')
}, 300);
```

Теперь первый аргумент для `setTimeout` - ваша анонимная функция. Когда придет время, она будет вызвана, и необходимый код внутри этой функции будет выполнен.

Comment: Да, так всё работает. Спасибо)